# connection refused from other time zone

Tags: java, web-services, security, glassfish, java-metro-framework

We have a webservice that run under glassfish 3.1.1 and metro.
We are using username authentification with symmetric key.
It works fine except for clients from other time zone . If they try to invoke the web service they get this  error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Creation Time is older than configured Timestamp Freshness Interval!
```

Is it possible to fix this without syncrhonizing the client system clock with the server ?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service will be called from a different time zone then you should use

```
RFC 2822 date format
```